# Show that if $p\mid m^2$ then $p \mid m$ and hence $p^2 \mid m^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility

> Show that if $p\mid m^2$ then $p \mid m$ and hence $p^2 \mid m^2$

I don't understand what is being asked of me. I thought this question was asking if $p$ divides $m^2$, then $p$ divides $m$, and hence, $p^2$ divides $m^2$.

$4$ divides $2^2$, but does not divide $2$. So Im trying to figure out what's being asked of me.

IF it's any help, this is for an abstract algebra class

Comment: $4$ is not prime.

Comment: I'm sure $p$ here is meant to be a prime. Otherwise you are right it obviously does not hold.

Comment: It doesn't say prime, but I'm going to assume that's what it means. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

If the statement were corrected to include that $p$ was a prime, then it's true. [And you might try to prove it; if you have unique factorization, then you get it very quickly. But you might also try to use the definition of a prime].

Comment: Would something reliable go along the lines of this:  if p divides m^2, than m^2 must have a factor of p in it. so when you break m^2 apart a multiple of p lies in there. m.m must be some multiple of p. So m. m = np for some integer n and prime number p?

Comment: Wait nevermind. That's not a proof of what I have to prove

Comment: @Aldmeri: I definitely recommend that you use the definition of [a prime element](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element), if you're familiar with it.